# Querying from BigQuery to Python

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to query data to bigquery with this code as mentioned in google docs:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
tab = client.query(""" SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("projects/projectid/locations/europe-west6/connections/system", "SELECT * FROM table") """)
return render_template('index.html', tab=tab.result())
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: ('Iterator has already started', <google.cloud.bigquery.table.RowIterator object at 0x7f86c1ef0160>)
```

Comment: Can you share which GCP documentation you used?